# Exact search match in Oracle full-text search

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to make Oracle Text Search score an exact match as 100 (or higher than the other matches).
I cannot get it to match exact, because it always seems to be doing a wildcard search for % even when the wildcard character "%" is not present.

Expected result is to only get 1 row with the following query:

```sql
select bf.text1, score(1)
 from bm_freetext bf
 where (contains(bf.text1, '{exact phrase}', 1) > 0);
```

Instead it return every row with "exact phrase" present:

[image]

It does not seem to make any difference, if there's a wildcard at the end of {exact phrase} or not (%)

The exact match should be inserted as the first sequence in the following query:

```sql
 select bf.text1, score(1)
 from bm_freetext bf
 where (contains(bf.text1, '
     <query>
      <textquery grammar="CONTEXT">
          <progression>
            <seq>{exact phrase}% - %{exact phrase}</seq>
            <seq>%{exact phrase}%</seq>
            <seq>exact and phrase</seq>
          </progression>
      </textquery>
      <score datatype="float" />
    </query>
 ', 1) > 0)
 order by score(1) desc;
```

Current result for the above query:

[image]